# Java Inner Class (not static)

Tags: java

I have a question about this topic:
An instance by a inner class need everytime an object of the same type of the guest class of the inner class. example:

```
public class GuestClass {

    class innerClass {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        innerClass test = new innerClass(); //does not work because 
                                            //I need a object of type GuestClass
        GuestClass iNeedYou = new GuestClass();
        innerClass nestClassObj = iNeedYou.new innerClass(); //it works 
    }
}
```

ok it's clear.
the innerClass object now points also to an GuestClass object (iNeedYou)
Now come my question:
an anonymous class is also a inner class right?
but with some difference:
A. I don't know the type of this object
B. it implements an interface.

but it is still an object by an inner class (anonymus but inner)

in fact if I do this:

```
public class GuestClass {
    private int numb = 100;

    class innerClass {
    }

    public void createAnAnonymusObject () {
        myInterface myAnObj = new myInterface(){
        int a, b;

        @Override
        public void print() {
            System.out.println(numb); //it works
        }};
        myAnObj.print(); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {                                   
        GuestClass iNeedYou = new GuestClass();
        iNeedYou.createAnAnonymusObject();  
    }
}
```

works because the anonymous inner object points to the outer object... so i can see the variable numb.

but why this works?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    myInterface myAnObj = new myInterface(){ //why does it work? in this case   
                                             //where is the outer object?
    int a, b;

    @Override
    public void print() {

    }};     
}
```

if the anonymous class is an inner class why it doesn't need an outer object?

Comment: What is 'myInterface'?

Comment: It can be instructive to use the `javap` tool (which comes with the JDK, last I checked) to dump the bytecodes produced by these different test cases.

Comment: @EJP because it mean a name of an interface -_-'

Comment: Obviously,but you haven't provided the definition, so we are left to guess or infer that. It should have been provided in the question.

Comment: I'm guessing that "myInterface" is a class that includes it's own version of `numb`.

Comment: @HotLicks Agreed. OP you need to post this interface.

Comment: myInterFace is an interface is not a class...

Comment: @GiovanniFar I'm voting to close this question. You haven't posted all the relevant code, and some of what you have posted manifestly isn't the real code. You were asked several times to fix that and you haven't. -1

Comment: Downvote remains. You've edited the question but still without providing the interface requested on three or four occasions. Without the reference to a member of an enclosing instance that you've just removed, my answer now applies.

Comment: Net-net:  You certainly *can* have an anonymous inner class in a static method, but it will be a static inner class and will have no access to the variables of the containing class.

Comment: @HotLicks 'Static' and 'inner' are mutually exclusive. That would be an anonymous *nested* class.

Comment: @HotLicks yes but why i cannot do the same thing also with a normal inner class? with a normal inner class i need everytime an object in a static (and not static) method. with the anonymous class no. i dont understand why there is this difference. thanks

Comment: *Because that's what 'inner' means.*

Comment: @EJP also anonymous class are inner class.

Comment: @GiovanniFar Not if they are based on interfaces. You don't seem to be reading what you're told here, even after you've agreed with it, as you did under my answer, where I told you exactly that an hour ago. Anonymous classes are *nested* classes. It isn't the same thing.

Comment: here
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.5
they said:
An anonymous class is always an inner class<br>for this reason i'm confused

Comment: @EJP - I suspect they've changed the terminology in the past dozen years or so since I was in the thick of this.  But "inner" vs "nested" is a rather nebulous distinction to the non-lawyer.  At issue is whether this embedded class (to use a neutral term) is static or not.  For regularly declared classes that's dependent on whether one says `static` or not in the declaration.  For anonymous classes it depends on whether the class is defined in a static method or an instance method -- the anonymous class declared in a static method is static just like a class explicitly declared with `static`.

Comment: Thanks now I understand sorry for before

Comment: @HotLicks They haven't changed the terminology and I think that statement is simply wrong: an anonymous class may well be `static`. Proof: `class Test {
  static Test t = new Test() { int t() { return 2; } };
  int t() { return 1; }
}` Clearly there can be no enclosing instance for `t` and decompiling `Test$1` will show that it is indeed a static nested class.

Comment: @EJP `Not if they are based on interfaces`---whether an anonymous class is based on an interface or not is orthogonal to whether the class is static or inner. All four combinations are possible.

Comment: The question of whether the type an anonymous class extends is itself static or inner is a concern completely separate from the fact that the class in anonymous. *Any* subclass of an inner class transitively requires an enclosing instance, a concern orthogonal to the enclosing instance which the *subclass* may require on its own.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - Well, when Sun initially introduced inner classes, prior to anonymous classes, I only remember them being termed "inner", never "nested".  If "nested" is now a distinction I suspect that it arose as the terminology was "hardened" over the next few years.  The rest of your comment indicates that you didn't read mine, or my answer, where I did indeed clearly demonstrate that an anonymous class *can* be static.  Why do you disagree with me and then go on to restate what I already said?

Comment: I see part of the confusion -- 15.9.5 states "An anonymous class is always an inner class (§8.1.3); it is never static (§8.1.1, §8.5.1)."  Reading the JLS is always fraught with peril, but I strongly suspect they mean that the `static` keyword is never used, not that an anonymous class can't be "static" in function.

Comment: @HotLicks The "nested" distinction entered the JLS at least as of Second Edition (more than a decade ago). The rest of your comment indicates that you misunderstood the rest of mine, which claims that the *statement in the JLS* is wrong.

Comment: @HotLicks As for the wording of the JLS, "static nested" is a well-defined term, the opposite of "inner". So you can even ignore the "never static" and focus on "always inner", which is wrong.

Comment: @HotLicks [This historical document](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/maintenance/JLS/innerclasses.pdf) proves that Java has never been in a stage where it had inner, but not anonymous classes. These were all introduced together in Java 1.1. The *nested* / *inner* distinction is in place as well.

Comment: I've probably had more practice interpreting Sun/Oracle specs than anyone else in this thread, and I know that they can be vague, contradictory, and very often subject to fine-grained interpretation.  In particular, when talking about a term like "static" they could be referring to the concept or purely to the keyword.  They also like to change their terminology.  The JLS 2nd didn't come out in final form until long after the inner class concept was introduced -- we got the info in "review" sections and then tried to figure it out.  The final arbiter, of course, was not any spec but the JCK.

Comment: Do you have any idea how many different versions of that document were produced?  I know I saw at least two -- neither in that final form.

Comment: @HotLicks Seems like you were exposed to a lot of noise at that time, clouding your memory :) My comment is, naturally, only about the public releases of Java, not the internal process which brought them about.

Comment: The main thing is to not get hung up on terminology.  Whether a class is "inner" or "nested" is a fine thing for lawyers to discuss, but the distinction is meaningless (or at least less meaningful than "static" or "non-static").

Comment: @HotLicks Terminology does not dictate reality, that's true, but when communicating with strangers it is vital for getting the information across. I have checked the JLS and realized that *inner class* doesn't at all mean "a class with an enclosing instance". It mostly implies restrictions on which type of members the class may have. Also, in the above discussed historical document, I found that *top-level class* doesn't mean non-nested; it means *non-inner*.

Comment: inner class everytime need an encolsing istance, there is an exception for the anonymous class when just implement an interface. because also the anonymous class if they extend another class need an enclosing istance. with the interface no because they are static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basically asking two questions here.

### Why does a non-static nested class require an enclosing instance?

Because it's assumed to have access to all non-static members of the outer class. Even if you don't actually use any of those, the compiler can't infer that the non-static nested class can be used safely in static context. You have to explicitly mark it `static` to allow this.

### Where and what is the enclosing object of the anonymous class created in this snippet?

```
public class OuterClass {

  private int nonStaticMember;

  private static int staticMember;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyInterface myAnObj = new MyInterface(){ //why it works ?? in this case   
                                             //where is the outer object?

    @Override
    public void print() {
       //nonStaticMember is not visible in this scope
       //staticMember is visible in this scope
    }};     
  }
}
```

In this case, your anonymous class has *no enclosing instance*. It's created in a static context, in the `main` method. You can instantiate `MyInterface` because all interfaces are implicitly static, even if defined inside another class. That's why the interface is visible at all. All of the non-static members of `OuterClass`, on the other hand, are not available in this scope so you're guaranteed not to use any of them. This is why there is no need to have a reference to an enclosing object. In fact, this is included in the language's specification.

Take a look at this [Java Language Standard excerpt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.2)

> Let C be the class being instantiated, and let i be the instance being
>   created. If C is an inner class then i may have an immediately
>   enclosing instance. The immediately enclosing instance of i (§8.1.3)
>   is determined as follows.
>
> If C is an anonymous class, then:
>
> - If the class instance creation expression occurs in a static context
>     (§8.1.3), then i has no immediately enclosing instance.
> - Otherwise, the immediately enclosing instance of i is this.
>
> (...)

I only quoted the most relevant part for this use case. Feel free to dive a little deeper into it.

Comment: this i understand, the question is: why the anonymus class can do that but a normal inner class no? it need the outerobject in this case, but the anonymus not! why there is this difference between them?

Comment: @GiovanniFar isn't `numb` a static variable in your last example? Otherwise, it wouldn't be visible in `main`.

Comment: maybe you dont understand what i mean. if you like delete the variable numb because my focus is not there. i don't understand why an object by anonymus class can be created without an outer object. like in the main method...

Comment: @GiovanniFar because this is how anonymous classes are created in static context. They don't need outer objects because they can't access the enclosing class' non-static members anyway. In a sense, they're implicitly static.

Comment: so if i understand an anonymus object can have an outer object (like in my example, and if the anonymus object is inside in his method he can see the variables of the outer object still like in my example) but in a static context like in the main method... the anonymous object to be created doesnt need the outer obj. sooo it can works with or without the outer object... i undesrtand? thx

Comment: No, Tom. If the anonymous class extends an inner class you still need an outer instance.

Comment: @EJP also if the anonymous object is inside in his method class  he can see the outer instance.

Comment: @EJP this doesn't seem to be the case, though. As I understand, `MyInterface` is just an arbitrary interface, not a subclass of some inner class here.

Comment: Exactly, and a nested interface is implicitly static, so he doesn't need an outer instance, as per my answer. It doesn't need an outer object because it extends/implements something static, not because it's in a static context itself.

Comment: @EJP ok but if i do the same thing in a method of an object my anonymous istance points to the outerObject, why?

Comment: @EJP I could instantiate an arbitrary top-level interface in there and I still wouldn't need an enclosing instance (yes, top-level classes are static). Frankly, I'm not sure we're even talking about the same behaviour. The question is missing some details on what `MyInterface` actually is.

Comment: Tom, that's exactly what I'm saying. You can instantiate an anonymous class based on an interface or nested static class in any context. You can only instantiate an anonymous class based on an inner class in a non-static context. Try it.

Comment: @GiovanniFar You didn't do the same thing. Your failing example is based on an inner class. Your working example is based on an interface.

Comment: @EJP my example is clear... i can do an istance of an anonymous object that implements an interface (myInterface); or i can also do an istance of an anonymous obj that extends another class. i'm speaking about the first possibility (interface), and about that sounds strange that it's possible to have an anonymous object that implements an interface with or without an outer object. because if you do that in a method of an object the anonymous object points to the outer if you do the same thing in a static method (example the main) your anonymous object does not point to an outer. but why??????

Comment: @EJP but I can instantiate an interface in a non-static context and still access non-static members of the enclosing class. The enclosing object will be there and the anonymous class' instance will have a reference to it. Its presence is determined by the context (static vs. non-static).

Comment: @GiovanniFar *Please post the interface!*

Comment: @tom so anonymous class has this more option:
static context doesnt have the outer obj
no static context has the outer obj it's right?

Comment: @EJP what changes if i do that or not? the question is not this... is not about the interface... is about how works the anonymous class

Comment: @GiovanniFar I decline to speculate without seeing all the code.

Comment: @GiovanniFar yes, that's how it is according to the specification.

Comment: @EJP myInterface have just 1 method and this method is print.

Comment: @Tom ok thanks, but why there is this difference... i mean why anonymous can have an outer obj or not (Dependes the context) but the inner no? why the inner have to be an outer in everycase ?

Comment: @GiovanniFar I'm beginning to undestand the confusion. You're asking two questions here. Let me edit my answer in an attempt to answer them properly.

Comment: @Tom ok thanks, i'm happy that u understand what i mean

Comment: Tom, I agree completely.

Comment: @EJP edited my answer. Hopefully, it's clear enough now. Please let me know if you find it better now.

Comment: Tom, 'static' and 'inner' are mutually exclusive, so 'non-static inner' is an oxymoron. You should probably say 'non-static nested' here, with maybe an '(inner)' somewhere.

Comment: @EJP thanks for catching that.

Comment: @EJP an epic one indeed :) Thanks a lot for helping me arrive at the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Anonymous2 {
    private int numb = 100;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyInterface myAnObj = new MyInterface(){ //why it works ?? in this case   
                                                 //where is the outer object?
        int a, b;

        @Override
        public void print() {
            System.out.println(numb); 
        }};     
    }
}

interface MyInterface {
    public void print();
}
```

Compiling:

```
C:\JavaTools>javac Anonymous2.java
Anonymous2.java:11: error: non-static variable numb cannot be referenced from a static context
            System.out.println(numb);
                               ^
1 error
```

As can be seen, the code that the OP claimed would compile doesn't.  So this entire question is irrelevant.

Comment: in this way for sure doesnt work... you have to do an istance of myAnObj in a method of Anonymous2 object

Comment: @GiovanniFar So the code you posted isn't the real code?

Comment: it is but look better in the first post where i use myAnObj... and where i created it... look you will see that i worked in a method of an object...

Comment: @GiovanniFar - It proves that the last code sequence in your original post is bogus -- I just copied it and changed the class names.  You ask "but why this works?", and the answer is that it doesn't.

Comment: @GiovanniFar No, it clearly is not. HotLicks has proven it. QED and +1

Comment: @ejp i edited i leaved the numb variable. but the part that you have to look and that compile is the second not the last. and i explain to you what i mean: in the second part of the code i can use the anonymous object that implement an interface and that can see the variable of the outer object. ok ?
in the last part you see the same things but without an outerobject.
and the question is: why anonymous class can have an outer object (if the context is not static) and not (if the context is static) but the normal inner class cannot use this rule because they need everytime an outerobject?

Comment: @GiovanniFar We've all lost interest: at least I certainly have. I answered your question as it *now* appears an hour ago, and Tom answered the other part an hour ago as well. The basic answer to both is 'because that's the way it's specified'. Next time provide everything requested, and make sure the code you post really does or doesn't compile.